# How to apply subset function to dataframe using lapply

Tags: r, list, dataframe, subset, lapply

I have a DataFrame of "dbGet_TRUE_EVENTS_DATA"

```
> dbGet_TRUE_EVENTS_DATA
   LONGITUDE LATITUDE DATE_START   DATE_END FLAG EQNUM
1      -39.5     80.5 2008-07-06 2008-07-10    1     1
2      -39.5     81.5 2008-07-06 2008-07-10    1     1
3      -38.5     80.5 2008-07-06 2008-07-10    1     2
4      -38.5     81.5 2008-07-06 2008-07-10    1     2
5      -39.5     79.5 2008-07-06 2008-07-10    1     3
6      -38.5     79.5 2008-07-06 2008-07-10    1     3
7      -39.5     79.5 2008-07-06 2008-07-10    1     4
8      -38.5     79.5 2008-07-06 2008-07-10    1     4
9      -39.5     79.5 2008-07-06 2008-07-10    1     5
10     -38.5     79.5 2008-07-06 2008-07-10    1     6
11     -39.5     79.5 2008-07-06 2008-07-10    1     7
```

and a list "TRUE_EVENTS_split_up"

```
> TRUE_EVENTS_split_up
$Fold1
[1] 3 4 6

$Fold2
[1] 5 7

$Fold3
[1] 1 2
```

I can subset data like the following:

```
newdata1 <-
  subset(dbGet_TRUE_EVENTS_DATA, EQNUM %in% TRUE_EVENTS_split_up$Fold1)
newdata2 <-
  subset(dbGet_TRUE_EVENTS_DATA, EQNUM %in% TRUE_EVENTS_split_up$Fold2)
newdata3 <-
  subset(dbGet_TRUE_EVENTS_DATA, EQNUM %in% TRUE_EVENTS_split_up$Fold3)
newdata <- list(newdata1 ,newdata2 ,newdata3 )
```

I would like to apply directly my subset on dbGet_TRUE_EVENTS_DATA. I know that I have to use lapply function but don't know how ?

```
> dput(dbGet_TRUE_EVENTS_DATA)
structure(list(LONGITUDE = c(-39.5, -39.5, -38.5, -38.5, -39.5, 
-38.5, -39.5, -38.5, -39.5, -38.5, -39.5), LATITUDE = c(80.5, 
81.5, 80.5, 81.5, 79.5, 79.5, 79.5, 79.5, 79.5, 79.5, 79.5), 
    DATE_START = structure(c(1215298800, 1215298800, 1215298800, 
    1215298800, 1215298800, 1215298800, 1215298800, 1215298800, 
    1215298800, 1215298800, 1215298800), class = c("POSIXct", 
    "POSIXt")), DATE_END = structure(c(1215644400, 1215644400, 
    1215644400, 1215644400, 1215644400, 1215644400, 1215644400, 
    1215644400, 1215644400, 1215644400, 1215644400), class = c("POSIXct", 
    "POSIXt")), FLAG = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), EQNUM = c(1, 
    1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 6, 7)), .Names = c("LONGITUDE", "LATITUDE", 
"DATE_START", "DATE_END", "FLAG", "EQNUM"), row.names = c(NA, 
-11L), class = "data.frame")

> dput(TRUE_EVENTS_split_up)
structure(list(Fold1 = c(3, 4, 6), Fold2 = c(5, 7), Fold3 = c(1, 
2)), .Names = c("Fold1", "Fold2", "Fold3"))
```

Comment: For this case, `lapply(TRUE_EVENTS_split_up,function(x)subset(dbGet_TRUE_EVENTS_DATA,EQNUM %in% x))` . But I would like to use `split` or  `tidyr::nest` to do it directly.

Comment: Thanks @Lerong, can you post your method using split or tidyr::nest